# Behavior of using-directive

Tags: c++

I am confused about using-directive.

According to C++11 standard §7.3.4 p.3,

> A using-directive does not add any members to the declarative region in which it appears.

Additionally, C++11 standard §7.3.4 does not deal with qualified name lookup.

Therefore, IMHO using-directive has no effect to qualified name lookup.
For example, I think that the following sample code should cause a compilation error.

```
#include <iostream>

namespace A {
    namespace B {
        int i = 1;
    }
    using namespace B;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << A::i << std::endl;
}
```

But both gcc and clang compile this code successfully.
(http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/rXPjE5k12yMtlvMg)

Furthermore, C++11 standard §7.3.1.1 says that an unnamed-namespace-definition behaves as if it were replaced by

```
inlineopt namespace unique { /* empty body */ }
using namespace unique;
namespace unique { namespace-body }
```

and shows following example (the unnecessary part were omitted).

```
namespace { int i; }    // unique::i

namespace A {
    namespace {
        int i;          // A::unique::i
    }
}

using namespace A;
void h() {
    i++;                // error: unique::i or A::unique::i
    A::i++;             // A::unique::i
}
```

This example says that `A::i` of function `h` can refer to the unnamed namespace member `i`.

Help me, I cannot understand any longer.

Would you teach me the right interpretation of using-directive?

Comment: I don't have time to look into the details now, but I believe the key point is that while it does not add members to the namespace, it makes their names accessible via that namespace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having 7.3.4

> A using-directive specifies that the names in the nominated namespace
>   can be used in the scope in which the using-directive appears after
>   the  using-directive. During unqualified name lookup (3.4.1), the
>   names appear as if they were declared in the nearest enclosing
>   namespace which contains both the using-directive and the nominated
>   namespace. [ Note: In this context, “contains” means “contains
>   directly or indirectly”. — end note ]
>
> A using-directive does not add any members to the declarative region
>   in which it appears.

Interpreting above it says a using-directive is pulling the names into a scope, but not the declaration (namespace member),
itself.

This might illustrate it:

```
namespace N {
    template <typename T> void f() {};
}

using namespace N;

// error: specialization of ‘template<class T> void N::f()’ in different
//        namespace
template <> void f<int>() {};
```

In the second example there are two unnamed namespaces:

Applying some little changes:

```
#include <iostream>

namespace { int i = 0; }    // unique::i

namespace A {
    namespace {
        int i = 1;          // A::unique::i
    }
}

using namespace A;

int main () {
    // i++; // error: unique::i or A::unique::i
    // The i having the value 1:
    std::cout << A::i << std::endl; // A::unique::i
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I had overlooked §3.3.6 p2.